# How to create an expression getting a property dynamically using LinqExpression in c#?

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I am trying to create a linq expression getting dynamically a property from a Student object based on a SearchFilter object parameter.

The problem is that Expression.Property(expr, string) asks for a string for the property name. And I cannot retrieve the string from the ParameterExpression. I tried this but I am stuck... The cast as a (string) off course does not work. Any clue on how to proceed instead ?

Check the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var student = new Student
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                Address = new Address
                {
                    City = "New York",
                    ZipCode = 10005
                }
            };
            var filter = new SearchFilter
            {
                Rule = "ZipCode"
            };

            var studentParamExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Student), "s");
            var filterParamExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SearchFilter), "filter");
            var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(
                CreateStudentAddressRuleAccessor(studentParamExpr, filterParamExpr),
                new ParameterExpression[] { studentParamExpr, filterParamExpr });
            var expression = lambdaExpr.Compile().DynamicInvoke(student, filter);
        }

        public static Expression CreateStudentAddressRuleAccessor(ParameterExpression student, ParameterExpression filter)
        {
            var ruleExpr = Expression.Property(filter, "Rule");
            string rule = (string)ruleExpr;

            var resultExpr = Expression.Property(Expression.Property(student, "Address"), rule);
            return resultExpr;
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchFilter
    {
        public string Rule { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is clear to me what you are trying to accomplish? What is the purpose of `filterParamExpr`? Why are you not just passing `filter` to `CreateStudentRuleAccessor`? Are you trying to create an `Expression` that dynamically uses the current value of the `filter` variable when evaluated to get a string property? Think about what you would have to do to do that directly in C# using a `string propName` variable. Also, I assume you realize the `"filter"` name of the `filterParamExpr` has nothing to do with the `filter` variable.

Comment: @NetMage I do not pass the filter object directly because the lambda requires ParameterExpression[]. But indeed by simply removing the filter from the list of lambda params and turning the type of the filter arg to SearchFilter works fine:

'var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda( CreateStudentAddressRuleAccessor(studentParamExpr, filter), new ParameterExpression[] { studentParamExpr }); var expression = lambdaExpr.Compile().DynamicInvoke(student);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lambda body does not require all of their arguments to be expressions.**
Remove the filter from the list of lambda params and turn the type of the filter arg to SearchFilter like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ...
   var studentParamExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Student), "s");
   var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(
      CreateStudentAddressRuleAccessor(studentParamExpr, filter),
                new ParameterExpression[] { studentParamExpr });
   var expression = lambdaExpr.Compile().DynamicInvoke(student);
   Console.WriteLine($"Lambda expression = {lambdaExpr}");
   Console.WriteLine($"Expression = {expression}");
}

public static Expression CreateStudentAddressRuleAccessor(ParameterExpression student, SearchFilter filter)
{
   var resultExpr = Expression.Property(Expression.Property(student, "Address"), filter.Rule);
   return resultExpr;
}
```